# awk command to create sha2 of individual column and paste into new file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file of having multiple rows. Using that original file I am creating one more files but in that new file i am taking only few columns of the original files.

What I have to do is, instead of just picking few columns and pasting in new files, I need to create sha2 of first column and paste in new file as plain value also as well as sha2 value.

Hope I am clear.

This is the awk command I am using to do the same.

```
 awk -F '|' -v  OFS='|' -v  var="10|" '(NR - 1) != 0  {$2=var$2; print $2,$3,$4,$5} (NR - 1) == 0   {print} ' $line > $subName$i$output
```

**INPUT**

```
2|0001001010000026316|531849|1150|101|01111991|00919323739251      |VIJAYPANDEY1191@GMAIL.COM                                   |VIJAY PANDEY                            |PART OF GROUND FLOOR & BASEMENT         |SHOPPER STOP SV ROAD ANDHERI WEST       |LANDMARK-ERSTWHILE CRASSWORD BOOK STORE |MUMBAI                        |400058
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT REQUIRES SHA2 VALUE OF 2ND COLUMN AND TO APPEND AS THE LAST COLUMN IN THE SAME ROW**

```
10|0001001010000026316|531849|1150|101|2e16abd9f3e3e368210b11faa5bfebdb6e001034b58cc9ad1c689dfd1f7eeacd
```

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and sample of expected output in your post and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 check my edits

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it please mention logic by which you are getting expected output too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 edited again.  I want to generate sha2 value of 2nd column and append it on the last column of the same row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
awk -F"|" -v var="10" '
    NR==1;
    NR>1{
        "echo "$2"|sha256sum" | getline shaoutput; 
        split(shaoutput, sha, " "); 
        print var, $2, $3, $4, $5, sha[1]
    }' OFS="|" file
```

Output :

```
10|0001001010000026316|531849|1150|101|2e16abd9f3e3e368210b11faa5bfebdb6e001034b58cc9ad1c689dfd1f7eeacd
```

I prefer to use `NR==1` and `NR>1` as it is more readable.

`NR==1;` is ok, no need to add `{print}`

For `NR>1`, I use `sha256sum` to generate the sha as awk does not have any function to do that (to my knowledge). I save the output in `shaoutput` variable, clean the output using `split`, then print what is needed.

I prefer not to store the output delimiter inside the `var` variable.
Using commas inside print will make awk use the `OFS` variable as delimiter.

**Edited**

As suggested by Ed Morton, an improved solution :

```
awk -v var="10" '
    BEGIN{
        FS=OFS="|"
    }
    NR==1;
    NR>1{
        shaoutput="";
        cmd="echo \047" $2 "\047 | sha256sum" ;
        if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ){
            shaoutput=line
            close(cmd)
        }
        split(shaoutput, sha, " ");
        print var, $2, $3, $4, $5, sha[1];
    }' file
```

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, I always learn new things and improve with your comments. I appreciate a lot. Edited

Comment: Should perhaps the SHA256 command not receive a newline at the end of the input?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk you can get away with setting `NF` although Ed is not going to like it:

```
awk '{ NF=5; "echo " $2" | sha256sum | cut -d\\\  -f1" | getline $(NF+1) } 1' FS='|' OFS='|'
```

You can accomplish the same with fewer portability issues with `paste` and `cut`:

```
paste -d'|' <(cut -d'|' -f1-5 infile) <(cut -d'|' -f2 infile | sha256sum | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

Comment: Excellent prediction - I don't like it :-). That use of getline can fail in various insidious ways, you're not quoting the value being passed to echo which introduces vulnerabilities and bugs due to globbing, etc., and even if/when it ever works it will only do so in some awks due to the non-portable/undefined behavior of setting NF to a lesser value, and it's just pointless to have shell call awk to call shell to call a pipeline of shell commands vs just calling that pipeline of commands directly from shell.