# Re-order fields from nth to NF-1 with awk

Tags: unix, awk, cut

My problem :
I have a pipe delimiter input file and I need to put the last column at first, drop the 2nd, and print from the third to the last-1.

Currently, this works with my 7 fields file :

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="|"; } {print $NF,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
```

But i am looking for something more automatic, which works with n number of columns

I have tried a loop, but it prints all fields on separate line.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="|"; } {for(i=2;i<=NF-1;++i)print $i}'
```

But this print all fields on separate rows, plus the first is not printed.

I have tried many another solutions but no luck so far...

Is there any option i'm missing ?

Input :

```
"PRILYYYTVENIZKEB@XXXX"|2017-09-08T09:46:40.000|"AUDIOTEL"|"Virement +"|25|"50747071"|6440bc7a8f41a96f89ee123159b7eb819a99767c9107b24e9d346eb3835f74a7
"CSRBQDVXJEFPACTKOO@AAA"|2020-02-11T10:02:20.000|"WEB"|"Virement +"|25|"51254683"|cd558b1319595aa63929d8cf3d8213ccc004aac089e6dd3bbad1d595ad010335
"WOGMKZLBHDFPACTKHG@ZZZZ"|2019-07-03T12:00:00.000|"WEB"|"Virement +"|195|"51080106"|f128a559267df0f9a6352fb40f65594aa8f5d01d5c3b90f471ffa0be07739c4d
```

Expected :

```
6440bc7a8f41a96f89ee123159b7eb819a99767c9107b24e9d346eb3835f74a7|2017-09-08T09:46:40.000|"AUDIOTEL"|"Virement +"|25|"50747071"
cd558b1319595aa63929d8cf3d8213ccc004aac089e6dd3bbad1d595ad010335|2020-02-11T10:02:20.000|"WEB"|"Virement +"|25|"51254683"
f128a559267df0f9a6352fb40f65594aa8f5d01d5c3b90f471ffa0be07739c4d|2019-07-03T12:00:00.000|"WEB"|"Virement +"|195|"51080106"
```

(email on 2nd is deleted, and hash on last is put on first).

---

Global context (maybe another solution more direct is possible) :

My goal is to replace the first field with a hash-calculated value of this field.

I use a temporary file to add my calculated field at the end of my file :

```
while read line
do
        echo -n "$line|"
        echo -n  $line | cut -d'|' -f1 | sed "s/\"//g" | tr -d '\n' | sha256sum | cut -d' ' -f1
done < $f_x_file_name.$f_x_file_extension > $f_x_file_name.hash.$f_x_file_extension ;
```

Thanks !

Regards

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output, edit to the original post, don't post as a comment.

Comment: I posted an answer to the question you asked first of how to swap fields. If you'd like a better way to `replace the first field with a hash-calculated value of this field.` as mentioned towards the end of your question you're doing then take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53762874/1745001 and post a different question, again with sample input/output, if you need help with that.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you mean by:

> put the last column at first, drop the 2nd, and print from the third
> to the last-1

then a more concise way of saying that would be:

> move the first column to the 2nd and move the last column to the first

which would be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$2=$1; $1=$NF; NF--} 1' file
```

for example:

```
$ echo 'a|b|c|d' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$2=$1; $1=$NF; NF--} 1'
d|a|c
```

Using `NF--` to delete the last column is undefined behavior per POSIX, if your awk doesn't support it then just change `NF--` to `sub(/\|[^|]*$/,"")`.

If I misunderstood what you're trying to do then edit your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Any folklore on which awks don't support `NF--`? I ran into a similar situation earlier today, decided to test it on some awks but they all coped with it. Surely I've seen it fail but can't remember which awk it was.

Comment: @JamesBrown No, sorry, but if I had access to either I'd test nawk and /usr/xpg4/bin/awk on Solaris.

Comment: @JamesBrown I just tried it on MacOS (`/usr/bin/awk --version` -> 
`awk version 20070501`) and `echo '1 2 3' | /usr/bin/awk '{NF--}1'` output `1 2 3`. gawk on the same box outputs `1 2`. Interestingly `echo '1 2 3' | /usr/bin/awk '{$1=$1; NF--}1'` also outputs `1 2` so what `NF--` does doesn't only depend on the version of awk you're running but also on what else you're doing in your specific awk script - I guess that's why they call the behavior "undefined" :-).

Comment: Yeah ok, I'm seeing that with Debian's original-awk,  `awk version 20121220`, also (but not in `awk version 20200625` I just ran into). Thank you, sir.

Comment: Thanks for answering !

This command provides what i expected :

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$1=$NF; NF--} 1'`

Answer (score 0):

based on the script, not your description, you want

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$1=$NF; NF--}1' file
```

example:

```
$ seq 5 | paste -sd'|' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$1=$NF; NF--}1'
5|2|3|4
```

Answer (score 0):

While in the current situation, this is easily implemented, I'm always wondering why there is no `concat` function which does the reverse operation of `split`:

- **`split(s, a[, fs  ])`:** Split the string `s` into array elements `a[1], a[2], ..., a[n]`, and return `n`. All elements of the array shall be deleted before the split is performed. The separation shall be done with the ERE `fs` or with the field separator `FS` if `fs` is not given. Each array element shall have a string value when created and, if appropriate, the array element shall be considered a numeric string (see Expressions in awk). The effect of a null string as the value of `fs` is unspecified.
- **`concat(a[, ofs ])`:** Concatenate the array elements `a[1], a[2], ..., a[n]` with `ofs` as field separator or `OFS` if `ofs` is not given. Numeric string values are converted to strings using `CONVFMT`. The first `n` array elements are concatenated, where such that `n+1 in a` returns 0.

The implementation of `concat` would read:

```
function concat(a,  ofs,  s,i) {
     ofs=(ofs=="" && ofs==0 ? OFS : ofs)
     i=1; while(i in a) { s = s (i==1?"":ofs) a[i]; i++ }
     return s
}
```

Using this function, you could then easily create an array with elements and assemble it as a string of fields:

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
{ n=split($0,a) }
{ a[2]=a[1]; a[1]=a[n]; delete a[n] }
{ print concat(a) }
```

---

See comments below for more information about this.

Comment: The reason there's no concat function is that it's easily done with other constructs (major tenet of the awk language to avoid language bloat - only provide constructs for tasks that are difficult to do with other constructs) and a version of it that only concatenates arrays with incrementing numeric indices with no gaps would be of limited use while a generic version of it would have to take into account the type of the indices and what order the array elements should be visited in. Its one of the many things that I also sometimes wish awk had but appreciate why it doesn't.

Comment: In a provided `concat()` btw there'd have to be some way to specify that no separator should be used so `ofs=(ofs==""?OFS:ofs)` would have to be modified to.`ofs=((ofs=="")&&(ofs==0)?OFS:ofs)` so `ofs` is only set to `OFS` if the function is called without an `ofs` argument. IMHO it's not worth worrying about, just thought it'd be worth pointing out one of the details that'd have to be addressed if a `concat()` function **were** going to be provided.

Comment: and yes given `foo(arg) { ... if ((arg=="") && (arg==0)) ...}` is how you test for an optional function argument not being present because only uninitialized variables (including function arguments) have the value zero-or-null.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the valuable input. I never thought about testing for both zero and empty-string to check if an argument is available or not.

Comment: FWIW top of my wish list for awk would be a single flag for setting both the input and output field separators. In my perfect world we'd have `IFS` for the Input Field Separator, `OFS` for the Output Field Separator, and `FS` (which can be set with `-F`) for both Field Separators (so `awk -F, ...` would set FS which now means both input and output field separators to `,` instead of todays `awk -F, -v OFS=, ...` or similar) which can be overridden by also setting either. But I'm not going to hold my breath :-).

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, I don't know how many times I write `BEGIN{FS=OFS="x"}`

Answer (score 0):

Modify the script where you calculate the hash.

```
while read -r line
do
   # hash from your command:
   # hash=$(echo -n  $line | cut -d'|' -f1 | sed "s/\"//g" | tr -d '\n' | 
   #        sha256sum | cut -d' ' -f1)
   # Slightly changed
   hash=$(cut -d'|' -f1 <<<"${line}"| tr -d '\n"' | sha256sum | cut -d' ' -f1)
   echo "${hash}|$(cut -d '|' -f2- <<< "${line}")"
done < "$f_x_file_name"."$f_x_file_extension" > "$f_x_file_name".hash."$f_x_file_extension"
```

or even easier:

```
while IFS='|' read -r firstfield otherfields
do
   hash=$(sha256sum <<< "${firstfield}" | cut -d' ' -f1)
   echo "${hash}|${otherfields}"
done < "$f_x_file_name"."$f_x_file_extension" > "$f_x_file_name".hash."$f_x_file_extension"
```